# Cannot import name 'Imputer' from 'sklearn.preprocessing' from pandas_ml

Tags: python, python-3.6

I am working on a project for my master and I was trying to get some stats on my calculations. I found a very cool tool to do this, called [panda_ml](https://pandas-ml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), but when I import it in my cell on jupyter like this:

```
from pandas_ml import *
```

It gives me this output error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-118-93009f7254d4> in <module>
      3 from sklearn import *
      4 from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
----> 5 from pandas_ml import *
      6 import math
      7 

~/anaconda3/envs/Lab1_B/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas_ml/__init__.py in <module>
      1 #!/usr/bin/env python
      2 
----> 3 from pandas_ml.core import ModelFrame, ModelSeries       # noqa
      4 from pandas_ml.tools import info                         # noqa
      5 from pandas_ml.version import version as __version__     # noqa

~/anaconda3/envs/Lab1_B/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas_ml/core/__init__.py in <module>
      1 #!/usr/bin/env python
      2 
----> 3 from pandas_ml.core.frame import ModelFrame       # noqa
      4 from pandas_ml.core.series import ModelSeries     # noqa

~/anaconda3/envs/Lab1_B/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas_ml/core/frame.py in <module>
      8 
      9 import pandas_ml.imbaccessors as imbaccessors
---> 10 import pandas_ml.skaccessors as skaccessors
     11 import pandas_ml.smaccessors as smaccessors
     12 import pandas_ml.snsaccessors as snsaccessors

~/anaconda3/envs/Lab1_B/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas_ml/skaccessors/__init__.py in <module>
     17 from pandas_ml.skaccessors.neighbors import NeighborsMethods                      # noqa
     18 from pandas_ml.skaccessors.pipeline import PipelineMethods                        # noqa
---> 19 from pandas_ml.skaccessors.preprocessing import PreprocessingMethods              # noqa
     20 from pandas_ml.skaccessors.svm import SVMMethods                                  # noqa

~/anaconda3/envs/Lab1_B/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas_ml/skaccessors/preprocessing.py in <module>
     11     _keep_col_classes = [pp.Binarizer,
     12                          pp.FunctionTransformer,
---> 13                          pp.Imputer,
     14                          pp.KernelCenterer,
     15                          pp.LabelEncoder,

AttributeError: module 'sklearn.preprocessing' has no attribute 'Imputer'
```

I am using Conda, I have my own env with all the packages, I have tried to install older versions of sklearn and pandas_ml but it did not solve the problem. I've searching around but it seems that no one had ever this problem...Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to uninstall properly and downgrading will work.

```
pip uninstall -y scikit-learn
pip uninstall -y pandas
pip uninstall -y pandas_ml

pip install scikit-learn==0.21.1
pip install pandas==0.24.2
pip install pandas_ml
```

Then import

```
from pandas_ml import *
```

Tested in `Python 3.8.2`

Answer (score 0):

I had `scikit-learn` version 0.22.1 installed recently and had a similar problem. Then I tried your solution under Python `3.7.2`, maintained the versions for `Pandas` `v0.25.1` and `Pandas ML` `v0.6.1` and it work like a charm!. I wonder when would be it safe to turn to a newer version of `scikit-learn`

Answer (score 0):

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
imp = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, copy=False, strategy="mean", )
```

No axis value is needed anymore